# Turn object into array, add object as new element

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, lodash

Trying to transform an object of objects:

```
var items: {
    item_a: {
        state: 'item_a status'
    },
    item_b: {
        state: 'item_b status'
    }
};
```

into an array of objects, whilst adding a new array element to the object (the object key):

```
var items = [{
    name: 'item_a',
    state: 'item_a status'
}, {
    name: 'item_b',
    state: 'item_b status'
}];
```

My naive attempt, which works, is thus:

```
var arrayOfItems = [];
for(var x in items){
    var itemObj = {
        name: x
    };
    for(var y in items[x]){
        itemObj[y] = items[x][y];
    }
    arrayOfItems.push(itemObj);
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this, using maybe something Underscore/LoDash?

Comment: When you are posting a question, please include all the requirements in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var newItems = _.map(items, function(item, key){
  item.name = key;
  return item;
});
console.log(newItems);
```

Comment: This mutates the original object. I feel that, this beats the important idea in functional programming, not mutating objects.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) for this:

```
_.map(items, function(item, key) {
    return _.assign({ name: key }, item);
});
// →
// [
//   {
//     name: 'item_a',
//     state: 'item_a status'
//   },
//   {
//     name: 'item_b',
//     state: 'item_b status'
//   }
// ]
```

Since `map()` always returns an array, you're halfway there. You just need the callback to generate your array items. You can use the [assign()](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) function to setup your new `name` property, and then add the rest of the properties.